# How do you create an android icon pack for the Google Play Store?

Tags: android, photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I want to know how to create an icon pack for download at the Google play store. I am fluent in Photoshop as well as Illustrator and I have the potential to recreate app logos that can match a theme a person may like (such as a dark/material theme for their android device). I just don't know how to go about it, much less how to start (what are the recommended dimensions for the icon picture, what dpi, etc). I have been looking on the Internet for help and assistance as well, but sadly there is nothing I can find that will tell me what to do. If it involves coding I am up for learning something new or anything different than coding I am up for learning as well. Thanks in advance to any help/guidance in the future!

Comment: There are a couple features out there to help create assets for particular uses.  This for one is a reference worthy of mention: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/ . It's not the only one out there though if you are looking to make your life a bit easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adaptive Icons seem to be the future of app icons.

Nick Butcher did a really great article on how to implement them:
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/implementing-adaptive-icons-1e4d1795470e

Android Studio 3.0 includes a new wizard that will help you create them:
[image: android studio icon wizard]
It allows you to select the foreground and the background and also can generate the legacy icons for you.

Answer (score 0):

The requirements for Graphic assets for the Play store are all listed in [this help article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1078870).

If you are trying to market your services to app developers, it is probably also you being aware of [store listing experiments](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/grow/store-listing-experiments).

This lets app developers test and prove that your icon or images brings them more (or fewer) installs. The results can be surprising. There are some videos at the bottom of that page which give some good tips.